# How to normalize edges weight between 0 and 1

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any way to normalize edges weights between 0 and 1?

for example in this graph:

[image]

How I can normalize all edges between 0 and 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you want to normalize it? There are different ways. You could divide everything by $58$ and then all edges will have value between $0$ and $1$.

You could also take the total weight of all edges leading out of a vertex, and then normalize with respect to that value. For instance, the edges leading out of vertex $1$ would become $5/7$ and $2/7$. Of course, this process yields a directed graph (e.g. the new edge from $1$ to $4$ would be $5/7$, but the new edge from $4$ to $1$ would be $5/68$).

Comment: why in the second normalisation would the new edge from 4 to 1 be 5/10 , and not 5 / ( 5 + 5 + 58) ? should not take into account all the sum of outgoing edges ?

Comment: it would be, there was a typo in my response, it is edited now. Thanks for catching it.